# Multi Tenant Razor pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, .net-core, razor-pages

I am trying to set up Razor Pages routing to allow different views to be rendered for different tenants.

I have a directory structure as follows:

```
/Pages
    Test.cshtml.cs
    /Tenant1
        Test.cshtml
    /Tenant2
        Test.cshtml
```

Given I am already able to decide which tenant is required, how is it possible to configure the routing to map some path eg `localhost:8080/Test` to either `Tenant1/Test` or `Tenant2/Test` views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use dynamic view content (via partial views).

With this solution, the `Test` page will dynamically load a different view depending on the route used to call it.

This means that you only have a single `Test` page but inside the `cshtml` file you will grab content from a partial view (more on that in a second).

First you will need to rename the files like so....

```
/Pages
    Test.cshtml.cs
    /Tenant1
        _Test.cshtml  // note it is prefixed with an underscore!
    /Tenant2
        _Test.cshtml  // prefixed with an underscore too.
```

> The naming convention for a partial view is to prefix the file with an underscore (`_`). This will immediately identify to someone looking at your project files as a "non-routable" page.

Then you add a little bit of logic to render the partial views...

**Test.cshtml**

```
@{
    switch(...)  // used a switch statement to illustrate the solution
    {
        case "Tenant1":
            await Html.PartialAsync("~/Pages/Tenant1/_Test.cshtml");
            break;
        case "Tenant2":
            await Html.PartialAsync("~/Pages/Tenant2/_Test.cshtml");
            break;
        default:
            throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You can read about partial views [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

**Extra: Using the same page model.**
I also noticed that you had wanted to use the same page model (meaning sharing `Test.cshtml.cs` for both. This is rather trivial, but for the sake of completeness of the answer here is how you would do that...

**/Pages/Test.cshtml.cs**

```
namespace Foo.Pages
{
    public class MySharedTestModel : PageModel
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

**/Pages/Tenant1/Test.cshtml** and **/Pages/Tenant2/Test.cshtml**

```
@page
@using Foo.Pages
@model MySharedTestModel 

...
```