# RazorPages IViewLocationExpander Equivalent

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-middleware

In MVC it was a relatively easy task to implement flexible multi tenant based applications by implementing and registering a custom implementation of IViewLocationExpander. What is the razor pages equivalent of this? The scenario is that Tenant1 has a custom version of PageX.cshtml, but Tenant2 uses stock and the folder sturcture is effectively as follows:

```
Pages
 - Tennant1
     - PageX.cshtml
     - PageY.cshtml
 - Tenant2
     - PageY.cshtml
 - PageX.cshtml
```

In MVC implementing IViewLocationExpander it was possible to check for the existence of the cshtml file when returning the view, and fallback to default if it did not exist.

IPageRouteModelConvention gives an opportunity to effectively apply across the board, but this does not satisfy the requirement.

What is the best approach to multitenant razor pages, that doesn;t have a large overhead?

Is it possible for example to intercept the request at a middleware level, check for the existence of the alternate version and invoke if present, else continue on the pipeline.

Comment: Have you ever seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54108337/multi-tenant-razor-pages) using partial views?

Comment: @XingZou yes, but this requires a great quantity of overhead. In MVC, this was a simple task. Using razor pages requires a large rethink to the point where you question the value.